# Error in test reservation Expedia Affiliate Network

Tags: android, ean-13

I have been integrating EAN APIs in one of my android application.
But unfortunately I getting following error"

```
{
        "HotelRoomReservationResponse": {
        "EanWsError": {
        "itineraryId": -1,
        "handling": "UNRECOVERABLE",
        "category": "EXCEPTION",
        "exceptionConditionId": -1,
        "presentationMessage": "TravelNow.com cannot service this request.",
        "verboseMessage": "Exception Caught: null"
        },
        "customerSessionId": "aa3baf02-68a5-498e-84f5-be88c8e9873e"
        }
}
```

I have verified all the parameters, advised by EAN support, like for test booking 'address1' should be 'travelnow' etc etc, also all mandatory parameters are there I believe.

[Reference](http://developer.ean.com/docs/book-reservation/examples/rest-reservation)

Please advise.

Comment: I am also working on EAN APIs. I got perfect response. I think issue in your URL..please check it again.

Comment: sorted.... for test booking address1 value should be travelnow